# How do I format data from a file into a list view?

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview

I have the following code, and my image shows the error. I cannot format the data so they are in their independent columns each.

```
    Call loadCustomerListView(obj_CustDetails.getFileName, lstViewAllCustomers)
    obj_CustDetails = New filehandling("CustomerDetails.txt")
    StockArray = obj_CustDetails.GetAllLines()


    inputSug = New InputSuggestion(ListData, StockArray, True, 76, 87)

    StockData = obj_CustDetails.GetAllLines
    Dim StockQuan() As String = obj_Stock.GetAllLines

    For i = 0 To UBound(StockQuan)

    Next
```

On the list view, you can see that the error is the data not formatting correctly

[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Class each Property to match your data.
When you pull the data each property must accommodate each value so then it will applied on each column.
Later, you create a list of your Class's objects and you load it on the grid.

```
Private Class MyClass
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set
            m_ID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ID As Integer
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return m_FirstName
        End Get
        Set
            m_FirstName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FirstName As String
    Public Property SecondName() As String
        Get
            Return m_SecondName
        End Get
        Set
            m_SecondName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_SecondName As String
End Class

Private Sub PopulateGrid()
    Dim test1 As New TestObject() With { _
          .ID = "1231", _
         .FirstName = "John 1", _
         .Text = "dfasfsdf1" _
    }
    Dim test2 As New TestObject() With { _
           .ID = "1232", _
         .SecondName = "FASDFASDF 2", _
         .Text = "FASDFADF 2" _
    }
    Dim list As New List(Of MyClass)()
    list.Add(test1)
    list.Add(test2)

    dataGridView1.DataSource = list
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work scene as I'm loading the data from a file and so it needs to read it from the object which the file is initialized at??

Comment: @J.North from each line you load from the file you should convert it to an object and it will work.